# Modal bootstrap no funciona con navbar fija

Tags: bootstrap, modal, navbar

Anteriormente formule mal la pregunta. Pido disculpas ya que soy novato.
Adjunto codigo. Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo un navbar de bootstrap y dentro puse dos modal, funciona todo perfecto pero despues quise dejar fija el navbar y ahi ya no funciona, le puse la clase fixed-top, se queda fija el navbar pero el modal abre y no se puede cerrar ni hacer nada.

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega un [example]

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

la verdad no encuentro una solución al 100% a tu problema, Estoy casi seguro que tienes un problema con el Z-Index, Prueba lo siguiente...

```
.modal-sticky {z-index: 2000;}


<div class="sticky-top modal-sticky">
<nav class="bg-black">
</nav>
</div>
```

Es la Unica manera que me funciono el Modal en mi navegador, espero te sirva

Comment: gracias pero no funciono